# "pdf_open: Not a PDF 1.[1-5] file." when typesetting TeX file in TextMate

Tags: xetex, textmate

I have a TeX file, which is typeset by `XeLaTeX`.

The file has `\includegraphics{coverimage.eps}` on the first page, and `coverimage.eps` is located in the same directory as the TeX file. OS: MacOS 10.6.5, TextMate 1.5.10, xelatex 3.1415926-2.2-0.9997.4 (TeX Live 2010)

If I run `xelatex doc.tex` in console, file compiles without errors, and eps file is included. If I typeset it in TextMate (xelatex engine is selected in preferences), I get the following error:

```
** WARNING ** pdf_open: Not a PDF 1.[1-5] file.
** WARNING ** Failed to include image file "./coverimage.eps"
** WARNING ** >> Please check if
** WARNING ** >> rungs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sPAPERSIZE=a0 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=%v -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -sOutputFile=%o %i -c quit
** WARNING ** >> %o = output filename, %i = input filename, %b = input filename without suffix
** WARNING ** >> can really convert "./coverimage.eps" to PDF format image.
** WARNING ** pdf: image inclusion failed for "coverimage.eps".
** WARNING ** Failed to read image file: coverimage.eps
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command PSfile (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(107.149, 124.566)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "PSfile="coverimage.eps" llx=0 lly=0 urx=408 ury=526 rwi=3809
```

and there is no image included in the resulting file (but text looks ok).

I am not sure whether it is the error of xelatex or TextMate LaTeX bundle. What I tried to do:

1. As I said, `xelatex doc.tex` from console works. The exact command line that TextMate uses is:

   ```
   xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error-style -synctex=1
   ```

   But it works from console too.
2. If I convert the image to pdf (and fix the .tex file accordingly), typesetting from TextMate works too.
3. I tried running `rungs` with parameters specified in the error message, and got valid .pdf file with image as a result.
4. I compared .log files from typesetting in TextMate and in console, they are absolutely identical except for this error message (in particular, version of `xelatex` is the same).

Does anyone know what can cause this? Please tell me if you need any additional information.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can replicate the problem.  The problem doesn't exist with TeXShop, however.  So it seems that it is something with TextMate itself.

Comment: That's why I initially posted this question to superuser.com. No idea why it got migrated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I tried searching for `Cannot open Ghostscript for piped input` phrase I mentioned in the comment and found [this message](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2004-December/011689.html). Added `/usr/local/bin` to `PATH` variable in TextMate and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Yes, this fixed the problem for me too.  I should have noticed the difference between the two paths.

Comment: Interesting. `which gs` is indeed located in `/usr/local/bin`. Interesting that TexLive would place some Ghostscript commands in `/usr/texbin` (like `rungs`) and others in `/usr/local/bin` (`gs` as well as all the `ps2pdf`, `...2...`, etc., utilities)

Answer (score 1):

As `rungs` is also provided by Ghostscript, my guess is that you have an older installation of Ghostscript on your machine.  Somehow, the PATH in TextMate is different than the path in your Terminal, and so the older version is getting called only within TextMate.

To test this, you can use TextMate's "Execute Line Inserting Result" (bound to ^R). In a new TextMate document, try the following commands:

`which rungs`

`rungs -v`

`echo $PATH` (note that TextMate adds its own resources to `$PATH`, so this will be different. Focus on the order of the system directories like `/usr/texbin` and `/usr/local/bin`.)

and check the result against your terminal.  If this is indeed the problem, then you can solve this issue by manually setting the `PATH` variable in TextMate's advanced preferences window to be the same as in your Terminal.

[image: TextMate's Advanced Preferences]

---

**Edit:** Does this minimal example compile for you, with either XeLaTeX or pdfLaTeX? I used `demo.eps` from `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/doc/latex/guide-to-latex/demo.eps`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \includegraphics{demo.eps}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought that this might be the problem, but on my system I have only one rungs, and the paths are the same: `/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/bin/CocoaDialog.app/Contents/MacOS:/usr/texbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/bin` from within TextMate and `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/alan/bin` in the shell. But 'which rungs` returns `/usr/texbin/rungs` in both. And I can replicate the problem.

Comment: @Alan: Interesting. I cannot replicate the problem. 

OS 10.6.5, TextMate 1.5.10, XeTeX 3.1415926-2.2-0.9997.4 (TeX Live 2010).

Comment: I have exactly the same setup.  Very weird.

Comment: @Alan, yes, and it's the same as the OP, too.  I wondered if something funky might be going on in the `tmbundle`, so I tried both the default version as well as the latest version on GitHub, but both worked fine for me. I'm stumped.

Comment: `which rungs` gives me `/usr/texbin/rungs` both in Terminal and TextMate, and `echo $PATH` results resemble Alan's too. Your minimal example typesets with the same error in TextMate (sorry, I should have provided such example myself). `pdflatex` (in TextMate) gives the following error `!!! Error: Cannot open Ghostscript for piped input`. Both `xelatex` and `pdflatex` successfully typeset this example from Terminal.